# Connecting to mongosh via VSC

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongo-shell

I have weird problem with VSC connection to Mongo...

So, I've set up my system variable and added to PATH bin file.

And when I'm connecting to mongosh via PowerShell that looks okay:

[image: mongo1]

Interesting is that when I'm trying connect from my VSC there is a problem as follow:

[image]

Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Close VSC. Modify PATH to include the directory where **mongosh** is located. Reboot your system.